# VSCode docker-compose debug - Attach to all services when debug starts

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, debugging, docker-compose

I'm developing dotnet with docker containers and I use docker compose to orchestrate them.
Today when I start debugging, VSCode asks me to select a container group and afterwards it requests me to select a service to attach to.
Then if I want to debug another service, I have to attach to it following the same procedure.

Following the official Microsoft post:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose
I've managed to debug my code by attaching to each service explicitly.

I wonder if there's a way to automate it and by clicking on the 'Start debug' have the VSCode attach to all my services for debug (like Visual Studio does).